# Lua - Getting values from nested tables

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table, nested-table

Okay so I have been searching everywhere for this, but nowhere has the answer.

I have a nested table (an example):

```
{
  {
    "Username",
    "Password",
    "Balance",
  },
  {
    "username1",
    "password1",
    1000000,
  },
  {
    "username2",
    "password2",
    1000000,
  },
}
```

The thing is I can't iterate a loop to view these tables, nor get values from the tables.
None nested tables can be accessed easily like:

```
print(a[1])
```

How do I loop them and get values from them?

Comment: What happens when you do `print(a[1])`? Did you try `print(a[1][1])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pairs` or `ipairs` to iterate over the table:

```
local t = {
  {
    "Username",
    "Password",
    "Balance",
  },
  {
    "username1",
    "password1",
    1000000,
  },
  {
    "username2",
    "password2",
    1000000,
  },
}

for _, v in ipairs(t) do
  print(v[1], v[2],v[3])
end
```

will print:

```
Username    Password    Balance
username1   password1   1000000
username2   password2   1000000
```

Comment: I think in this case ipairs is a better choice

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
a =  {
   { "Username", "Password", "Balance", },
   { "username1", "password1", 1000000, },
   { "username2", "password2", 1000000, },
}
```

Then the second element of `a` will be `a[2]`, the table `{ "username1", "password1", 1000000, }`. If hyou print it it will look similar to `table: 0x872690` - its just just how tables are printed in Lua by default. To access the inner fields you just use the same indexing operators. For the first field we do `a[2][1]`, for the second we do `a[2][2]` and so on.

```
 for i = 2, #a do
     print(a[i][1], a[i][2], a[i][3])
 end
```